# Как вычесть число из DataDridView по выбранному ComboBox (C#,Access)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, access, combobox

[image: screen]

Пользователь выбирает в ComboBox товар и вводит число, при нажатии на обновить происходит вычет.

Comment: Для ввода чисел используйте `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Получаем текущий элемент из датагрид:

```
int currentValue = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Количество"].Value);
```

2. Получаем количество которое нужно отнять

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

3. Отнимаем количество от текущего значения

```
int total = currentValue - count;
```

4. Закидываем получившееся значение обратно в датагрид:

```
dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Количество"].Value = total
```

Comment: Спасибо большое